# Importing local jar through maven gives fully qualified name of the class

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, executable-jar

I am using my local jar project in another project through a maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>some.groupid</groupId>
   <artifactId>some.artifactid</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0-RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The jar is getting liked to the project but when I try to access any class from it, say com.companyname.app.Abc; it is imported as com.companyname.app.Abc and not just Abc with import statement separate.

I even tried putting import statement separately, but that did not work.
The IDE I am using is IntelliJ.

Comment: Is There another abc already?

Comment: No... in fact when there was.. we changed package structure of imported jar file

Comment: You may need to tell your IDE to rebuild its information about your project.  IntelliJ has a restart option that allows you to discard caches.

Comment: IDE issue apart, you can also try to see if maven clean was run for the project where the dependency was declared. Perhaps some old reference to that earlier class remains.

Answer (score 0):

It was pom related issue where few of the plugins were causing the issue.
I tried creating project from scratch and got the difference.